# Horizontal and vertical centering in xltabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, xltabular

I have an `xltabular` table, and I need help with centering the left-hand column, both horizontally and vertically. I do not know if it is possible. I've tried to use the `m` column type from the `array` package, but it didn't help.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{3D2B1F}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newlength\mylen
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\definecolor{M2}{HTML}{A8730F}
\definecolor{M}{HTML}{DFAA48}            
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}[1]{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c X}
\caption{Descripción de las actividades a realizar en cada sesión.}
\label{tab:secuenciacion}\\
\arrayrulecolor{M}
\toprule
\textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Nº Sesión}}} &  \textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Descripción}}}  \\
\toprule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\arrayrulecolor{M}
\toprule
\textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Nº Sesión}}} &  \textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Descripción}}} \\
\toprule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead
\textbf{1} & Planteamiento del problema de estudio de la Cinemática. ¿Cómo podemos saber qué trayectoria sigue un objeto, y por qué siempre es la misma? Repaso de conceptos matemáticos que serán básicos en la UD: cálculo vectorial, introducción a las derivadas y uso en funciones polinómicas. Representaciones gráficas.
\\
\midrule

\textbf{2} & Actividad de debate sobre los sistemas de referencia (explicación de la que usa el GPS). Introducción a los parámetros que caracterizan el movimiento: trayectoria, posición, desplazamiento y velocidad (media e instantánea). Carácter vectorial de las magnitudes.
\\
\midrule

\textbf{3} & Actividad de debate acerca de qué le ocurre a la velocidad durante un viaje en coche. La aceleración media e instantánea. Componentes intrínsecas de la aceleración.
\\

\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}
```

My output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain vertical centering of the contents of the first column, you need to run `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`. This is explained on page 3 of the user guide of the `tabularx` package.

I would also (a) replace the two interior `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace` directives, (b) assign color "M" to `\bottomrule` (in the `\endlastfoot` group), and (c) get rid of the whitespace padding at the edges of the `xltabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm, right=2cm, 
            top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}

%% don't load the inputenc and fontenc packages under XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} % default: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{3D2B1F}
%\usepackage{tabularx} % <-- no longer needed
\usepackage{xltabular} % <-- new
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % <-- new

\newlength\mylen
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\definecolor{M2}{HTML}{A8730F}
\definecolor{M}{HTML}{DFAA48}            
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont} % you sure about this?

\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{ltablex} % really?
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}[1]{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref} % it's usually a good idea to load this package *last*


\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}c X @{}}

\caption{Descripción de las actividades a realizar en cada sesión.}
\label{tab:secuenciacion} \\
\arrayrulecolor{M}
\toprule
\textcolor{M2}{Nº Sesión} &  
\textcolor{M2}{\textbf{Descripción}}  \\
\toprule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead

\arrayrulecolor{M}
\toprule
\textcolor{M2}{Nº Sesión} &  
\textcolor{M2}{\textbf{Descripción}} \\
\toprule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead

\arrayrulecolor{M}
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


1 & Planteamiento del problema de estudio de la Cinemática. ¿Cómo podemos saber qué trayectoria sigue un objeto, y por qué siempre es la misma? Repaso de conceptos matemáticos que serán básicos en la UD: cálculo vectorial, introducción a las derivadas y uso en funciones polinómicas. Representaciones gráficas.
\\
\addlinespace %\midrule

2 & Actividad de debate sobre los sistemas de referencia (explicación de la que usa el GPS). Introducción a los parámetros que caracterizan el movimiento: trayectoria, posición, desplazamiento y velocidad (media e instantánea). Carácter vectorial de las magnitudes.
\\
\addlinespace %\midrule

3 & Actividad de debate acerca de qué le ocurre a la velocidad durante un viaje en coche. La aceleración media e instantánea. Componentes intrínsecas de la aceleración.
\\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{3D2B1F}
\newlength\mylen
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\definecolor{M2}{HTML}{A8730F}
\definecolor{M}{HTML}{DFAA48}            
\usepackage{xltabular}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}[1]{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c X}
        \caption{Descripción de las actividades a realizar en cada sesión.}
        \label{tab:secuenciacion}\\\arrayrulecolor{M}\toprule
        \textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Nº Sesión}}} &  \textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Descripción}}}  \\\toprule
        \arrayrulecolor{black}
        \endfirsthead
        \arrayrulecolor{M}\toprule
        \textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Nº Sesión}}} &  \textcolor{M2}{\textbf{{Descripción}}} \\\toprule
        \arrayrulecolor{black}
        \endhead
        \textbf{1} & Planteamiento del problema de estudio de la Cinemática. ¿Cómo podemos saber qué trayectoria sigue un objeto, y por qué siempre es la misma? Repaso de conceptos matemáticos que serán básicos en la UD: cálculo vectorial, introducción a las derivadas y uso en funciones polinómicas. Representaciones gráficas.
        \\
        \midrule        
        \textbf{2} & Actividad de debate sobre los sistemas de referencia (explicación de la que usa el GPS). Introducción a los parámetros que caracterizan el movimiento: trayectoria, posición, desplazamiento y velocidad (media e instantánea). Carácter vectorial de las magnitudes.
        \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{3} & Actividad de debate acerca de qué le ocurre a la velocidad durante un viaje en coche. La aceleración media e instantánea. Componentes intrínsecas de la aceleración.
        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious: What's the motivation for replacing the OP's `\setmainfont{Arial}` with `\usepackage{libertinus}`?

Comment: @Mico Does libertinus allow you to use the Arial font? It was the only way I could set the document to the Arial font.

Comment: @DavidMoldes - As you show in the code you posted, and as I show in my answer, one can execute `\setmainfont{Arial}` *without* loading the `libertinus` package.